# Maximizing expected gain in a social network with probability

Tags: algorithm, e-commerce, social-networking, graph-algorithm

I am required to solve a specific problem.
I'm given a representation of a social network. 
Each node is a person, each edge is a connection between two persons. The graph is undirected (as you would expect).
Each person has a personal "affinity" for buying a product (to simplify things, let's say there's only one product involved in this whole problem).

In each "step" in time, each person, independently, chooses whether to buy the product or not.
There's *probability* invovled here. A few parameters are taken into account:

1. His personal affinity for the product,
2. The percentage of his friends that already bought the product

The gain for a person buying the product is 1 dollar.

The problem is to point out X persons (let's say, 5 persons) that will receive the product in step 0, and will maximize the total expected value of the gain after Y steps (let's say, 10 steps)

The network is very large. It's not possible to simulate all the options in a naive way.

What tool / library / algorithm should I be using?

Thank you.

P.S.
When investigating this matter in google and wikipedia, a few terms kept popping up:

- Dynamic network analysis
- Epidemic model

but it didn't help me to find an answer

Comment: What happens if I've already bought the product? Am I done, or can I buy a second one? Does owning one or more instances of the product affect my buying probability? If I can buy more than one, how does this affect my friends? (Do I count as two, or just one?)

Comment: Hi! You can buy only one, and once you've bought one- you're done. (I think this covers all the questions).

Comment: Can you say what kind of time complexity you are looking for, given the huge size of the network? If you are looking for linear time, i.e. making a decision based on the local environment of each node, you will probably have to use some kind of heuristic.

Comment: heuristic is probably the way to go, yes. There's no specific demand for time complexity

Answer (score 1):

Generally, people who have the most neighbours have the most influence when they buy something.

So my heuristic would be to order people first by the number of neighbours they have (in decreasing order), then by the number of neighbours that each of those neighbours has (in order from highest to lowest), and so on.  You will need at most Y levels of neighbour counts, though fewer may suffice in practice.  Then simply take the first X people on this list.

This is only a heuristic, because e.g. if a person has many neighbours but most or all of them are likely to have already bought the product through other connections, then it may give a higher expectation to select a different person having fewer neighbours, but whose neighbours are less likely to already own the product.

You do not need to construct the entire list and then sort it; you can construct the list and then insert each item into a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29), and then just extract the highest-scoring X people.  This will be much faster if X is small.

If X and Y are as low as you suggest then this calculation will be pretty fast, so it would be worth doing repeated runs in which instead of starting with the first X people owning the product, for each run you randomly select the initial X owners according to a probability that depends on their position in the list (the further down the list, the lower the probability).

Comment: There are a few types of "centrality" of a node in a social network graph:  Degree centrality ("the number of neighbours" as you sugguested),  Closeness centrality (the more central a node is the lower its total distance to all other nodes),  Betweenness centrality (Betweenness centrality quantifies the number of times a node acts as a bridge along the shortest path between two other nodes) and more. I'm not sure that the right way to go is the Degree centrality.

Comment: So try ordering people by those other centrality criteria too, and see which criterion tends to do better :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the concept of [submodularity](http://submodularity.org/submodularity-slides.pdf), a pretty powerful mathematical concept. In particular, check out **slide 19**, where submodularity is used to answer the question "Given a social graph, who should get free cell phones?". If you have access, also read the [corresponding paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=956769). That should get you started.

Comment: It does look interesting. Do you know if there's some implementation of this?

Comment: There's [SFO](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~krausea/sfo/), a Matlab/Octave Toolkit for submodular function optimization. It's briefly described [in this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1756044).